# BackgroundJobs do not let you get Users with IRepository

Tags: aspnetboilerplate, abp

**Use case:**
I need to pull a user record based on the ARGS coming from the BackgroundJob

```
public class ULBackgroundJob : BackgroundJob<ULJobArgsDto>, ITransientDependency, IULBackgroundJob
{
 private readonly IRepository<User, long> _userRepository;
 public ULBackgroundJob
 (IRepository<User, long> userRepository)
  {
    _userRepository = userRepository;
  }

 public  override void Execute(ULJobArgsDto args)
 {
  User user = _userRepository.FirstOrDefault(args.UserId);
 }
}
```

**Results:**
I always get zero results and I have checked that the user id value exists.

**Suspected Issue:**
The SQL that is generated inserts "@__ef_filter__IsMayHaveTenantFilterEnabled_1=1" into the query so I suspect I need to somehow get that set to Zero when I run from a BackgroundJob..?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to disable `IMayHaveTenant` filter to view cross-tenant entities:

```cs
using (CurrentUnitOfWork.DisableFilter(AbpDataFilters.MayHaveTenant))
{
    User user = _userRepository.FirstOrDefault(args.UserId);
}
```

You can read more about data filters in the ASP.NET Boilerplate documentation: https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Data-Filters

Comment: Yip! that fixed the issue. Much thanks @aaron, appreciate it.